# Include a property from to-one relationship in propertiesToFetch in NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchrequest

Problem:
For simplicity, I have two NSManagedObjects (A and B) where B has a to-one relationship to A. In my propertiesToFetch, using B as the entity type, I have a number of B properties. This works however what I want is to also include a property (e.g. 'name') of A from the to-one relationship.

Suggestions?

Edit:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchR = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:ClassName(B)];
fetchR.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active = %u",1];
fetchR.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchR.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [self propertyDescriptionFor:@"name" inEntity:ClassName(B)],
                            [self propertyDescriptionFor:@"age" inEntity:ClassName(B)],
```

`// Here is where I want to add something like "a.name"`

```
                            nil];
```

Comment: Please show some code. What entity are you fetching in your fetch request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the `propertyDescriptionFor:inEntity:` method (where is it defined?), but you can just provide an array of strings in `propertiesToFetch`:

```
fetchR.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"age", @"a.name", nil];
```

and to-one relationships should "just work".

Comment: Martin: Not only does this work it also educated me that I don't need the attribute descriptors (which I encapsulated in the 'propertyDescriptor:inEntity' message).